# Dart: Static fields inaccessible from instances?

Tags: dart

There are a few fields on a class that should never change and should be the same across all instances. I would like to make these fields `static const`, but I am having a hard time accessing them because Dart makes it  very clear that `Static fields cannot be accessed through instances`.

Is the only way to access them to call the class itself? What if a function took an instance and needed to infer the class using only the instance object in order to access its static fields?

Answer (score 0):

### How to access static fields?

static members are tied with the class, not with the object. If you want a field to be same in all instances of the class, then accessing it through the class makes more sense and, yes, it is the right and the only way.

### What if a function took an instance and needed to infer the class using only the instance object in order to access its static fields?

If you want to access the static members inside a function, why not access it through the class level? Without seeing your actual code we can't say what problem you are facing.